# How can I pass an url as value on a querystring and then get it back as plain text

Tags: c#

I wonder if I would have encoding problems with the code below, I just need to know the url in querystring, and how can I retrieve it back without enconding problems.

```
  string currentWebUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;

  string fullLink = String.Format("{0}?ClientCode={1}&ClientSiteCode={2}&currenturl={3}",
                                  Link, ClientCode,
                                  clientSiteCode, currentWebUrl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the URL will appear encoded in the address bar, but that should be fine.

When you want to retrieve it without the encoding you can use [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx).

For example:

```
string qs = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["currenturl"].ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?